# Move Index to last row in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to programmatically delete the last row in my Datagridview when a user clicks a button.  As of now, the program will scroll down and highlight the last row, but only deletes the row where the index is at.  So, I need to move the indexer (triangle indicator) to the last row.  How do I do this??

```
 If LftMtr_Data_Grid.RowCount >= 2 Then
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = LftMtr_Data_Grid.RowCount - 2 'scroll to the last row
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows(LftMtr_Data_Grid.RowCount - 2).Selected = True 'select the last row
        LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows.RemoveAt(LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentRow.Selected) 'delete selected row
    End If
```

Thank you

Comment: add a language tag, this is VB or VB.net i guess

Answer (score 0):

The `CurrentRow` is the row containing the active cell. By setting the `Selected` property to true, the row is only highlighted but not active.

To make the last row as active i.e. to make the row as `CurrentRow` use the `CurrentCell` property. Set any of the cell in the last row as `CurrentCell` before removing the row.

```
LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentCell = LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows(LftMtr_Data_Grid.RowCount - 1).Cells(0);
LftMtr_Data_Grid.Rows.RemoveAt(LftMtr_Data_Grid.CurrentRow.Index);
```

Comment: Okay, makes sense in theory but I tried your code example but still doesn't work.  If I manually highlight or select the last row and then click my "delete" button, it works fine.  It deletes each row all the way to the top row with each click of the "delete" button, which is good.  But the program is still not automatically selecting and making active the last row.  Is there a way to attach the program/solution file to these posts?

Comment: Disregard my last comment.  I got it.  I forgot to change the "dataGridView1" in your code example to "LftMtr_Data_Grid".  Thank you.